# How to query a ES to fetch names of all customers which have relase as 4.0

Tags: elasticsearch

i have lots of indexes in my ES clusters all having a common index pattern name as instance-*

The following is just one example of stored in ES DB :

```
{
"_index": "instances-i-0643d7ba-2016.08.15-08:19:10",
"_type": "type_name",
"_id": "1",
"_version": 1,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"index": "i-0643d7ba",
"instanceid": "i-0643d7ba",
"timestamp": "2016-08-15T08:00.02",
"system": {
"kernelrelease": "3.13.0-74-generic",
"memoryfree": "3.48 GB",
"memorytotal": "3.68 GB",
"processorcount": "1",
"timezone": "UTC",
"operatingsystem": "Ubuntu",
"uptime": "157 days",
"hostname": "fra01-he-dev-LBi-0643d7ba",
"is_virtual": "true",
"blockdevices": "xvda,xvdb",
"hardwaremodel": "x86_64",
"netmask": "255.255.255.0",
"blockdevice_xvda_size": 42949672960,
"uniqueid": "007f0100",
"packages": {
"openssh-server": "1:6.6p1-2ubuntu2.6",
"libssl1.0.0": "1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.18",
"openjdk-7-jre-headless": "7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.14.04.1",
"linux-image-virtual": "3.13.0.79.85",
"openssl": "1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.19"
},
"ipaddress": "10.21.17.51",
"lsbdistdescription": "Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS",
"macaddress": "06:ed:95:f5:9b:bd",
"operatingsystemrelease": "14.04",
"processor0": "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50GHz",
"fqdn": "fra01-he-dev-LBi-0643d7ba.eu-central-1.compute.internal",
"lsbdistcodename": "trusty"
},
"ansible.isv_alias": "brainlabag",
"ansible": {
"inventory_hostname": "10.21.17.51",
"stack_name": "fra01_he_dev",
"vendor_id": "6310519",
"EMS_URL": "brainlabag.dev.sentinelcloud.com/ems",
"YPS_URL": "fra01-he.dev.sentinelcloud.com/YPServer",
"ansible_eth0": {
"macaddress": "06:ed:95:f5:9b:bd",
"mtu": 9001,
"device": "eth0",
"promisc": false,
"ipv4": {
"netmask": "255.255.255.0",
"network": "10.21.17.0",
"address": "10.21.17.51"
},
"active": true,
"type": "ether"
},
"group_names": "haproxy",
"release": "4.0",
"isv_alias": "brainlabag",
"ansible_machine_id": "2a4f44fbd2d0e82f7521d45d5697d615",
"ansible_nodename": "fra01-he-dev-LBi-0643d7ba"
},
"webapps": {
"haproxy": {
"service": "haproxy"
}
},
"alias_list": [
"noemalife"
,
"brainlab"
]
}
}
```

I need to actually query the ES for all instances and get all those `alias_list` which have `release` as '4.0' . I tried to write the following query :

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/instances-*/_search?pretty' -d '{ "query": { "match": { "ansible[]release" : 4 }}}'
```

this just returns :

```
{
  "took" : 674,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1568,
    "successful" : 1568,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the `ansible.release` field?

Comment: it is a string fields in your  document, while  your are trying to search it as double fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your `ansible.release` field is mapped.

If it's mapped as a string, you should be able to query it like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/instances-*/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "_source": ["ansible.isv_alias", "ansible.release"], 
  "query": { "term": { "ansible.release" : "4.0" }}
}'
```

Otherwise, if it's mapped as a double, you should be able to query it like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/instances-*/_search?pretty' -d '{ 
  "_source": ["ansible.isv_alias", "ansible.release"], 
  "query": { "term": { "ansible.release" : 4.0 }}
}'
```

Comment: okay, is there a way just to get the isv_alias & ansible.release, i mean i just want a list kind of thing